# Are there any industry usage for gas thermometer?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, temperature, measurements, gas

I've been searching on this for a while now. Are there any specific advantages and disadvantages for using gas thermometer? Are there any specific industry usage for this kind of thermometer?

Comment: Is that a thermometer for measuring gas temperature or a thermometer using gas as the medium of expansion?

Comment: page 1item 9 from google search using your exact title : http://www.fratellimagni.com/inert-gas-thermometers.htm : "Our industrial thermometers ... are particularly suited for thermal and naval machinery and for use in ovens and kilns."

Comment: `thermal and naval machinery and for use in ovens and kilns`, what I mean is specifically what part in `naval machinery` do we need to use the gas thermometer?

Comment: @DirkBruere, yes. What I mean is a thermometer that uses gas as the medium of expansion.

Answer (score 1):

Advantages

- Very accurate ( In fact its accuracy allows it to be utilised to calibrate other
  thermometers)
- Wide Range
- Independent of gas used

Disadvantages

- Large and bulky(inconvenient to carry and handke)
- Slow to Respond (due high heat capacity)
- Expensive to manufacture and keep

I'm not sure about its use in any specific industries.